# A mathematical function for: Adding one to x if x is decimal

Tags: algorithms

I was wondering if there is a mathematical function for this:

If `x` is a decimal value, we subtract all decimal values from `x` and add 1.

Allow me to demonstrate:

```
1.00000000000001 = 2
2013.00123456789 = 2014
5.5 = 6
5.1 = 6
3.333333 = 4
7 = 7 <------ This is not a decimal value
```

If a math function does not exist for this, how do we mathematically do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the ceiling function and is usually denoted by $\lceil x \rceil$.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you. I learned something new today! Oh how much I love learning.

Comment: Before you agree that the ceiling is your answer, you should tell us what you want to happen for negative numbers.